# Touch/interact underneath ScollView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have a image carousel underneath a vertical ScrollView. I want to be able to slide some content on top of my image carousel. You can see in the current way I am implementing it **there is an issue**. I can no longer interact with my image carousel.

**I would like to be** able to scroll content on top of my carousel, but when there is not content on top, I would like to be able to use my carousel like normal. If possible,
**I would also like** to be able for the scrolling to not bounce back to where it started, but to stay where it is left. If I scroll my content to the top of the screen, it needs to stay at the top of the screen.

I have attached some code as to how I am rendering the scrollView and the carousel but every line of code can be found on my **snack example** [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/venuedetails-scroll). It reproduces my issue exactly.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf', flex: 1}}> 
      <View style={{position: 'absolute',}}>
          <Carousel/>
      </View>
      
      {/* beginning of white box below image*/}
      <ScrollView style={{height: scale(500)}}>
      <View style={styles.whiteBox}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', top: scale(15), left: scale(20)}}></View>

          {/* grey body in white text box*/}
        <View style={styles.greyBody}></View>
      </View>
      {/* end of white box below image*/}
    
      {/* grey body in white text box*/}
        {/* beginning of description*/}
      <View style={{bottom: scale(340),left: scale(25), position: "absolute", backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 15, color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
              Description
          </Text>
      </View>

      {/* beginning of View more text*/}
      <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: scale(400), left: scale(25), height: scale(100), width: scale(300),}}>
          <Text>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quo dolorum ponderum, nam veri molestie constituto eu. Eum enim tantas sadipscing ne, ut omnes malorum nostrum cum. Errem populo qui ne, ea ipsum antiopam definitionem eos.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
          </Text>
      </View>
      </ScrollView>
      {/* End of View more text*/}
      {/* End of description*/}
      </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you make a repro on https://snack.expo.dev/ ?

Comment: I did...4th bolded word, last sentence. I thought I made it obvious:(

Comment: My bad Justin, checking it now.

Comment: All good! Was just worried I lost ya interest! Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: I did not see any content except the carousel on android, could you make sure the snack works on Android?

Comment: I have been using it on IOS, ill get android working and shoot you a comment when I do!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242516/discussion-between-justin-priede-and-hugo-gresse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using absolute positioning for both of your views, that is an absolute position for `Carousel` and the `ScrollView` below it. We can debug the issue by adding a `zIndex: 2` to the `ScrollView` in `App` and set `backgroundColor: "red"` which enables us to see the issue here:

- The `ScrollView` in `App` is in fact **on top** of the `Carousel`.

This might be intended since we want to scroll "over" the `Carousel`. However, it disables the ability to `touch`, e.g. scroll, the `Carousel`.

This can be easily fixed by changing the following:

- Remove `{height: scale(500)}` of the `ScrollView` in `App`,
- Add `{marginTop: 250, overflow: "visible"}` to the `ScrollView` in `App`.

The top margin removes the part which is actually `on top` of the `Carousel` and the `overflow: "visible"` still allows us to scroll the `ScrollView` in `App` over the `Carousel` while scrolling the `Carousel` works now.

Notice that the text has shifted to the bottom now. We can fix this by

- Change `top: scale(400)` of the view that contains your text to `top: scale(200)`.

I have made a fully working [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/venuedetails-scroll) using your initial code. Notice that I have only tested this on iOS. Android might behave differently.

Since I have only changed `App.js`, here is the updated code of `App.js` which fixes the issue.

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, } from 'react-native';

import Carousel from './Carousel';
import {
  scale,
  verticalScale,
  moderateScale,
  ScaledSheet,
} from 'react-native-size-matters';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import ViewMoreText from 'react-native-view-more-text';

export default function App() {
  return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf', flex: 1}}> 
      <View style={{position: 'absolute',}}>
          <Carousel/>
      </View>
      
      {/* beginning of white box below image*/}
      <ScrollView style={{marginTop: 250, overflow: "visible"}}>
      <View style={styles.whiteBox}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', left: scale(20)}}></View>

          {/* grey body in white text box*/}
        <View style={styles.greyBody}></View>
      </View>
      {/* end of white box below image*/}
    
      {/* grey body in white text box*/}
        {/* beginning of description*/}
      <View style={{bottom: scale(340),left: scale(25), position: "absolute", backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 15, color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
              Description
          </Text>
      </View>

      {/* beginning of View more text*/}
      <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: scale(200), left: scale(25), height: scale(100), width: scale(300),}}>
          <Text>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quo dolorum ponderum, nam veri molestie constituto eu. Eum enim tantas sadipscing ne, ut omnes malorum nostrum cum. Errem populo qui ne, ea ipsum antiopam definitionem eos.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
          </Text>
      </View>
      </ScrollView>
      {/* End of View more text*/}
      {/* End of description*/}
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  whiteBox: {
    height: scale(175),
    width: scale(300),
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: scale(25),

    
  },
   distanceBox: {
    height: scale(30),
    width: scale(80),
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: scale(190),
    left: scale(45),
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
    busyView:{
      height: scale(20), 
      width: scale(40), 
      backgroundColor: '#ffe6f3', 
      borderRadius: 20, 
      justifyContent: 'center', 
      alignItems: 'center',  
    },
    pinkBubble: {
      height: scale(20),
      width: scale(40), 
      backgroundColor: '#ffe6f3', 
      borderRadius: 20, 
      justifyContent: 'center', 
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    greyBody: {
      backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf', 
      width: scale(255), 
      height: scale(75), 
      alignSelf: 'center', 
      borderRadius: 15, 
      top: scale(70)
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey David! Finally checked this out in depth... is there a way to make it so the scroll stops in place when you release rather than shooting back down or up to its original position?

Comment: If I remember correctly, then this is a standard behavior on iOS. Have you tested this on Android as well? I am not sure if we can prevent this easily.